# Is it possible to write an android app that would communicate with an arduino board?

Tags: android, arduino, connectivity, wireless

At the moment I have a nRF24L01+ 2.4GHz wireless transceiver for my arduino board and I wanted to write an app on my android device (LG G3) that would start the operation of a servo motor (HS-322HD Deluxe HITEC SERVO) on the arduino. I was wondering if it was possible to have the arduino and the android device communicate with the wireless transceiver?

Comment: unless your android has a software-defined radio, or that transceiver uses wifi or bluetooth, no, you won't be able to.

Answer (score 1):

If your Arduino board has one of these:

- Wifi Module
- Bluetooth Module

Yes - it is possible!